# Cómo completar un archivo PDF con datos de formulario en Java

Tags: java, pdf, backend, itext

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Java donde necesito completar un archivo PDF con datos de un formulario. La idea es que cuando un usuario complete un formulario en mi aplicación, los datos se inserten automáticamente en un archivo PDF predefinido. El problema viene que no se como hacer que los datos del formulario se ingresen en el archivo PDF que tengo, como podría hacerlo?

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que puedan proporcionar.

Comment: Usa jasperreports para generar tu reporte, necesitarás descargar las librerías de jasper a tu aplicación. Lees la información del formulario y desde tu aplicación se los pasas al reporte para que se llene. Luego puedes hacer con el reporte lo que quieras, guardarlo o mostrarselo al usuario en pantalla.

Comment: si lo conozco pero no me lo soluciona, estuve mirando itext pero aun asi debería de crear el PDF desde 0 y no aparecería igual... y tiene que ser una plantilla en concreto...